# Blazor - change UI

Tags: user-interface, blazor

Current code:

```
 <div class="col-2 border border-gray-200 rounded autocomplete col-2-autocomplete @TextSearch">
                <div class="labelFilter">
                    <span>Text search</span> 
                </div>
                <div id="freeTextInputGroup" class="input-group mb-3 c-box-shadow">
                    <input type="text" @bind-value="@FreeTextString" class="form-control text-input c-text-input @FreeTextFilterSelectedStyle" placeholder="Ex.: example"
                       aria-label="FreeText" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" aria-describedby="FreeText-input">
                    <button class="inner-clear-button" style="visibility:@FreeTextClearButtonVisibility" @onclick="ClearFreeText">&#10006</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success search-button" type="button" id="add-free-text-button">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

"Text" should be on line 1, "Enter text to search" on line2 and Input and button on third line.

When I use <br/ >,  it does not work as expected. Would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-12 border border-gray-200 rounded autocomplete col-2-autocomplete @TextSearchFilter">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <span>Text search</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <span>Enter text to search</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="freeTextInputGroup" class="input-group mb-3 c-box-shadow">
                <input type="text" @bind-value="@FreeTextString" class="form-control text-input c-text-input @FreeTextFilterSelectedStyle" placeholder="Ex.: JNO"
                   aria-label="FreeText" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" aria-describedby="FreeText-input">
                <button class="inner-clear-button" style="visibility:@FreeTextClearButtonVisibility" @onclick="ClearFreeText">&#10006</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success search-button" type="button" id="add-free-text-button">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I Hope this helps you...